# Laptop lost power and all my data is lost but exists in /media/user/longstring/

Tags: boot, 18.04, mount, hard-drive

I put my laptop to sleep mode and it lost power and the battery died. So I connected it back to the main power, started it up and logged in.
When I logged in, it logged my in as if I installed a fresh version of Ubuntu, all my pictures, data, software, packages were lost.

I checked `Disk usage analyser` and saw that all my data is located in:
`/media/USER/29e41d7b-3ff9-4ac7-874d-aaaaaaaaxxx/`

I checked `Disks` and the HDD the data is located on is `Mounted at /boot/efi`
My Ubuntu is installed on my SSD which is showing as FAT (32-bit version) — Not Mounted

My SSD is on `/dev/sdb1` and my HDD is on `/dev/sda1`.
I just checked and my `Filesystem partiation 2` where the data is held is on `Ext4 (version 1.0) — Mounted at /media/USER/29e41d7b-3ff9-4ac7-874d-aaaaaaaaxxx`

I have no idea why it's done this.

My question is, how to I load the profile within the `/media` dir to get all my data back?
Or how do I need to unmount the HDD?
Thank you